# Apply python logging format to each line of a message containing new lines

Tags: python, logging

I would like to include an id associated with the request for **every** log line in a log file. I have the mechanism for retrieving the request id via a logging filter working fine.

My problem is that when a log line contains a newline, the line of course get wrapped onto a "bare" line. Is there a way to tell the logging library to split the message, and apply the format to each element of the split?

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter(
        "%(requestid)s\t%(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.debug("blah\nblah")
```

Output:

```
xxx blah
blah
```

Desired output:

```
xxx blah
xxx blah
```

Comment: You should probably be doing something different with your logs. Aside from tracebacks, newlines *really* don't belong in log messages, at least when you're logging to a file.

Comment: I'm capturing the output of several subprocesses (conda, docker-py etc), and redirecting them into my own application log file. These logs are multi-line.

Comment: I would be using a tool like [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) to parse my logfiles.

Comment: Logstash is not appropriate for the task I'm working on, but thanks anyway

Comment: @WayneWerner unfortunately, `logging.Logger.exception` appends a newline-separated traceback to the message.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Though this is not the best way to go about this, but this will help you without changing a lot of code.

```
import logging


class CustomHandler(logging.StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomHandler, self).__init__()

    def emit(self, record):
        messages = record.msg.split('\n')
        for message in messages:
            record.msg = message
            super(CustomHandler, self).emit(record)


log = logging.getLogger()
handler = CustomHandler()
formattor = logging.Formatter("xxx:%(message)s")

handler.setFormatter(formattor)

log.addHandler(handler)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    log.debug('hello\nhi')
```

Output:

```
xxx:hello
xxx:hi
```

Comment: Works perfectly for my purpose. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
message = "blah\nblah"
logger.debug(message)
```

You could use

```
message = "blah\nblah"
for line in message.split("\n"):
    logger.debug(message)
```

The principle here is that each module should have its own responsibilities. If the logger has the responsibility to prepend an ID to each message, it is the caller's responsibility (that is, "yours") to give it properly partitioned messages.

Comment: Unfortunately that would require changes in a lot of application and library code. That's why I'm looking for a solution within the logging module itself.

Comment: Well, then you have a problem of excessive coupling. Can't you create some `DecoratedLogger` wrapping the `logger` module, and inject it in your application?

Comment: Why would that require a lot of changes? It's just feeding the logger line by line instead of one big line. It should be a matter of a `for loop`.
also you can trade split("\n") for a splitlines()`for line in message.splitlines()`

Comment: This would require each call to logger to be wrapped in some line split method. Its kinda overkill. Instead I could recommend to overwrite logger's `debug` (or other) methods. But still, that's a workaround.